How to create an action to show an image from local files in QGIS 3.36.3 in Windows 11?
I've been trying to follow the tutorial laid out for QGIS 3.34. (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html#follow-along-creating-an-action), but apparently the menu options have changed from that, and now the action I try to create doesn't work.
The closest I've gotten to something happening is to set the Type to "Open URL" and the Action Text to "open [%image%]", in that it does not give me an error message. However, it does not open any kind of an image either.  I apologise for my screenshot being partially in Finnish.

What is the correct combination of Type and Action Text to get the image to work on Windows with QGIS 3.36.3. if otherwise following the linked tutorial?

Simply add the path without any other characters, e.g.:
C:/Users/**[your_path]**/your_filename.jpg

Depending on what you want to do with the action, be sure you have checked the box Canvas (on your screenshot this seems not to be the case, if in finnish the checkboxes are in the same order). Like this, when you activate the action, you can click on a vector feature and the image opens.
Successfully tested with QGIS 3.36.3 on Win 10.



I had the path saved under the image, so I just removed the "open" part from in front of it and just left the [%image%], and it worked exactly as you explained. Thank you!
